# Is there a $3$-dimensional shape such that for any given volume that shape will have the greatest possible surface area?

Tags: geometry

I was just thinking about this studying for a biology test as for cells a greater surface area to volume ratio is desirable, so I wondered if there was a theoretically optimal shape that would maximize this ratio. I thought it might be that there is no such shape as you could just add folds to the surface indefinitely but I don't know if that is truly the case.

Comment: There's no upper bound on the surface area given a fixed volume (think of a very long and thin rectangular prism) and it can even be infinite (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_horn). Surely in biology you don't just want a large surface area but also some kind of restriction on the diameter so it doesn't take too long for molecules to be transported between different parts of the cell.

Comment: **Off-Topic**: Assuming that you accept Darwinism, there is a separate issue.  Assume (perhaps wrongly) that the greater the surface area per volume, the better, regardless of other considerations.  This doesn't necessarily make it *game over*, regardless of the complexity in evolving from (for example) an ameoba to a human.  Some chain of mutations must occur that lead to the high surface area shape.  Absent the occurrence of such mutations, it becomes irrelevant how desirable such a cellular shape would be.

Comment: This was more of a thought inspired by biology rather than a question about biology itself but thank you for your answers it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to show that there is no maximum surface area associated with a given volume is to consider very long cylinders (biologically, roughly the shape of a worm).  The volume $V$ of a cylinder of radius $r$ and height (or length if laid horizontally) $h$ is:

$$V = \pi r^2h$$

For a given volume, say $V^*$ we can therefore express $h$ in terms of $r$:

$$h=\dfrac{V^*}{\pi r^2}$$

The surface area $A$ is:

$$A=2\pi rh+2\pi r^2$$

Substituting for $h$:

$$A= \dfrac{2V^*}{r}+2\pi r^2 > \dfrac{2V^*}{r}$$

Given the constant $2V^*$ in the numerator, we can therefore make $A$ as large as we like by choosing a sufficiently small value of $r$.